# Ionic 2 Prompt Alert focus on text input

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am creating an ionic 2 application for android and ios. I have an alert controller that prompts the user for a text input, however when the alert pops up I would like the keyboard to focus on the input, and for the placeholder text to be highlighted. Currently you must tap on the text input for the keyboard to pop up. Is this possible to implement?

here is my alert controller code:

```
let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: this.name,
    message: this.nameMessage,
    inputs: [
      {
        name: 'name',
        placeholder: this.name
      },
    ],
    buttons: [
      {
        text: this.save,
        handler: data => {
          resolve(data.name);
        }
      }
    ],
    enableBackdropDismiss: false
  });
  prompt.present();
```

Answer (score 5):

This is my solution.

First

```
inputs: [
    {
      id: "autofocu",
      ......
    }
  ],
```

And then

```
alert.present()
.then(() => {
  document.getElementById('autofocu').focus();
})
.catch()
```